# MySQL Join and Echo Result

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli, echo

I was attempting to do a simple JOIN and when try to load the page it is blank. When I enter the query. I was attempting to have it print the query. I know how to print results however was having trouble printing the join.

```
SELECT user.name, course.name
    FROM `user`
    INNER JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id;
```

in my SQL on the PHPmyAdmin it returns

```
NAME        Course
Alice       HTML5
Bob         HTML5
Caroline    CSS3
```

---

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("URL,"USERNAME","PASS","DB");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user.name, course.name
FROM `user`
INNER JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id;");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['user.name'] . " " . $row['course.name'];
  echo "<br>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thank you for any insight...

Comment: I was going to edit your post to add the additional quote after `URL` but that could be the actual problem. Could you confirm this?

Comment: SO's syntax highlighter is talking to you *and me*. Do fix that please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to use `$row['user.name']` it should be `$row['name']` but as you have two columns with the same name as `name` so you have to change allocate them to other variables.

**[HINT]:** Check the new query and the `echo` in the while loop.
Please make these changes:

```
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASS","DB");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT user.name as username, course.name as coursename
    FROM `user`
    INNER JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id;");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['coursename'];
        echo "<br>";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: That worked swell!
Cheers,
I'm glad I wasn't too far gone there!

Comment: if i use select * from user INNER JOIN course on user.course=course.id; then how do echo fetch result ?